# Extract text between certain symbols using Regular Expression in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a series of expressions such as:

```
"<i>the text I need to extract</i></b></a></div>"
```

I need to extract the text between the `<i>` and `</i>` "symbols". This is, the result should be:

```
"the text I need to extract"
```

At the moment I am using gsub in R to manually remove all the symbols that are not text. However, I would like to use a regular expression to do the job. Does anyone know a regular expression to extract the between `<i>` and `</i>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If there is only one `<i>...</i>` as in the example then match everything up to `<i>` and everything from `</i>` forward and replace them both with the empty string:

```
x <- "<i>the text I need to extract</i></b></a></div>"
gsub(".*<i>|</i>.*", "", x)
```

giving:

```
[1] "the text I need to extract"
```

If there could be multiple occurrences in the same string then try:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "<i>(.*?)</i>", simplify = c)
```

giving the same in this example.

Answer (score 11):

This approach uses a package I maintain **qdapRegex** that isn't regex but may be of use to you or future searchers.  The function `rm_between` allows the user to extract text between a left and right bound and optionally include them.  This approach is easy in that you don't have to think of a specific regex, just the exact left and right boundaries:

```
library(qdapRegex)

x <- "<i>the text I need to extract</i></b></a></div>"

rm_between(x, "<i>", "</i>", extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "the text I need to extract"
```

I would point out that it may be more reliable to use an html parser for this job.

Comment: +1 for pointing out an html parser should be used for this text

Answer (score 7):

If this is html (which it look like it is) you should probably use an html parser.  Package `XML` can do this

```
library(XML)
x <- "<i>the text I need to extract</i></b></a></div>"
xmlValue(getNodeSet(htmlParse(x), "//i")[[1]])
# [1] "the text I need to extract"
```

On an entire html document, you can use

```
doc <- htmlParse(x)
sapply(getNodeSet(doc, "//i"), xmlValue)
```

Comment: IMO this is the best answer as it is the most reliable.  I came across these slides on parsing HTML that I found to be excellent: http://gastonsanchez.com/work/webdata/getting_web_data_r4_parsing_xml_html.pdf

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following approach with `gregexpr` and `regmatches` if you don't know the number of matches in a string.

```
vec <- c("<i>the text I need to extract</i></b></a></div>",
         "abc <i>another text</i> def <i>and another text</i> ghi")

regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(?<=<i>).*?(?=</i>)", vec, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "the text I need to extract"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "another text"     "and another text"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<i>((?:(?!<\/i>).)*)<\/i>
```

This should do it for you.