# Extract specific text within content

Tags: regex, r

I am working on email content which is dumped as dataframe value in row , and this has to be separated as different based on starting from:  untill till next from:

Sample data:

```
"______________________________________________ 
From:   Kumar M,  
Sent:   Tuesday, 21 October 2014 7:30 AM
To: Deo, Ravinesh; G S, Venkatesh;
Cc: Monteleone, Elif; Kabyanga, Isaac
Subject:    FW: Please Approve the Qlik  Access.


Hi Ravi,

We will work on the providing David access to Ql and an email will be sent out once the access is set up.   

Regards,
Santhosh

______________________________________________ 
From:   Deo, Ravinesh  
Sent:   Tuesday, 21 October 2014 7:20 AM
To: Kabyanga, Isaac; Kumar M, Santhosh
Cc: Monteleone, Elif
Subject:    FW: Please Approve the Qlikview Access.

Hi Isaac/Santhosh,

Appreciate if you can grant access to David Dennis for GPA – Timor.

David is CEO Timor Leste.

Thanks
Ravi

_____________________________________________
From: Dennis, David (Timor) 
Sent: Tuesday, 21 October 2014 11:34 AM
To: Deo, Ravinesh
Subject: FW: Please Approve the Q GPA Access.

Here you go - appreciate your help Rgds

______________________________________________ 
From:   Dennis, David (Timor)  
Sent:   Thursday, 9 October 2014 11:33 AM
To: Buchanan, Geoffrey (Solomon Islands)
Subject:    Please Approve the Qlikview Access.

Hello,

Can you please review the attached form and click ' Manager Approval' to approve.

Thanks"
```

i have refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809847/extract-text-between-certain-symbols-using-regular-expression-in-r?s=1%7C2.7698) and i have used this below code

```
ex <- gsub("^[from:](.*?)[from:]$", "",impordata$Problem.Description[i] )
```

but this gives all the mails in particular row !

**Desired Output:**

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809847/extract-text-between-certain-symbols-using-regular-expression-in-r?s=1%7C2.7698)

```
From:   Kumar M,  
    Sent:   Tuesday, 21 October 2014 7:30 AM
    To: Deo, Ravinesh; G S, Venkatesh;
    Cc: Monteleone, Elif; Kabyanga, Isaac
    Subject:    FW: Please Approve the Qlik  Access.


    Hi Ravi,

    We will work on the providing David access to Ql and an email will be sent out once the access is set up.   

    Regards,
    Santhosh
```

[2]

```
From:   Deo, Ravinesh  
    Sent:   Tuesday, 21 October 2014 7:20 AM
    To: Kabyanga, Isaac; Kumar M, Santhosh
    Cc: Monteleone, Elif
    Subject:    FW: Please Approve the Qlikview Access.

    Hi Isaac/Santhosh,

    Appreciate if you can grant access to David Dennis for GPA – Timor.

    David is CEO Timor Leste.

    Thanks
    Ravi
```

[3]

```
 From: Dennis, David (Timor) 
    Sent: Tuesday, 21 October 2014 11:34 AM
    To: Deo, Ravinesh
    Subject: FW: Please Approve the Q GPA Access.

    Here you go - appreciate your help Rgds
```

[4]

```
From:   Dennis, David (Timor)  
    Sent:   Thursday, 9 October 2014 11:33 AM
    To: Buchanan, Geoffrey (Solomon Islands)
    Subject:    Please Approve the Qlikview Access.

    Hello,

    Can you please review the attached form and click ' Manager Approval' to approve.

    Thanks"
```

and used `regmatches`

```
#Converted a row as vector to apply regmatches
vec <- as.vector(impordata$Problem.Description[1])

matc <-regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(^[from:]).*?($[from:])", vec, perl = TRUE))
```

No use of this too,

Can somebody correct it ! or provide some help

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: @karthikmanchala i have given the desired output above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `strsplit` fucntion.

```
> strsplit(gsub("(?s)^_+\\s+", "", x, perl=T) , "_+\\s*(?=From:)", perl=T)[[1]]
[1] "From:   Kumar M,  \nSent:   Tuesday, 21 October 2014 7:30 AM\nTo: Deo, Ravinesh; G S, Venkatesh;\nCc: Monteleone, Elif; Kabyanga, Isaac\nSubject:    FW: Please Approve the Qlik  Access.\n\n\nHi Ravi,\n\nWe will work on the providing David access to Ql and an email will be sent out once the access is set up.   \n\nRegards,\nSanthosh\n\n"
[2] "From:   Deo, Ravinesh  \nSent:   Tuesday, 21 October 2014 7:20 AM\nTo: Kabyanga, Isaac; Kumar M, Santhosh\nCc: Monteleone, Elif\nSubject:    FW: Please Approve the Qlikview Access.\n\nHi Isaac/Santhosh,\n\nAppreciate if you can grant access to David Dennis for GPA – Timor.\n\nDavid is CEO Timor Leste.\n\nThanks\nRavi\n\n"               
[3] "From: Dennis, David (Timor) \nSent: Tuesday, 21 October 2014 11:34 AM\nTo: Deo, Ravinesh\nSubject: FW: Please Approve the Q GPA Access.\n\nHere you go - appreciate your help Rgds\n\n"                                                                                                                                                           
[4] "From:   Dennis, David (Timor)  \nSent:   Thursday, 9 October 2014 11:33 AM\nTo: Buchanan, Geoffrey (Solomon Islands)\nSubject:    Please Approve the Qlikview Access.\n\nHello,\n\nCan you please review the attached form and click ' Manager Approval' to approve.\n\nThanks"
```

Comment: I used this , as i have edited in question but its not usefull, im getting `[[1]]
character(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `strsplit`:

```
splits <- strsplit(paste0(vec, collapse = "\n"), "_{45}")[[1]][-1]
cat(splits) 
cat(splits[1])
# _ 
# From:   Kumar M,  
# Sent:   Tuesday, 21 October 2014 7:30 AM
# To: Deo, Ravinesh; G S, Venkatesh;
# Cc: Monteleone, Elif; Kabyanga, Isaac
# Subject:    FW: Please Approve the Qlik  Access.
# 
# 
# Hi Ravi,
# 
# We will work on the providing David access to Ql and an email will be sent out once the access is set up.   
# 
# Regards,
# Santhosh
```