# Extract a section of a string in R

Tags: r, string

I need to extract a section of a string form a Twitter output. The extract I'm doing is with this code:

```
some_tweets = searchTwitter('weather', n=4, lang='en')
st <- twListToDF(some_tweets)
st[,"statusSource"]
```

And the output is something like:

```
[1] "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>"  
[2] "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Facebook</a>"               
[3] "<a href=\"http://instagram.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Instagram</a>"                         
[4] "<a href=\"http://www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Hootsuite</a>"
```

What I want to extract is the last section like:

```
Twitter for iPhone
Facebook
Instagram
Hootsuite
```

What I want to do is to count the number of entries I have for each of the types of connections.

Any ideas on how I can extract the strings I need to count them?

Comment: Use `gsub("<[^>]+>", "", st[,"statusSource"])`

Comment: Also and maybe closer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26809847/1000343

Comment: i checked a few solutions but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks Wiktor, that works for me

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using the `rvest` package.

```
x <- c("<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
       "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\">Facebook</a>",
       "<a href=\"http://instagram.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Instagram</a>",
       "<a href=\"http://www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Hootsuite</a>")


library(rvest)

unname(sapply(x, FUN = function(m) html_text(html_nodes(read_html(m), "a"))))
[1] "Twitter for iPhone" "Facebook"           "Instagram"          "Hootsuite"
```